# Typescript Tests Issue With Absolute Import Linting

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, tslint

Inside my `tsconfig.json`, I have these exclusions.

```
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
```

Which is needed so the editor doesn't squawk at jest methods. However I need the following rule for absolute import

```
    "baseUrl": "."
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue you have with types is jest methods, you should definitely have a look at [ts-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest). It will allow you to create jest config, that will make jest run typescript as code preprocessor and will strictly type jest methods.

Opting out of type checking for tests seems tempting at first, but I personally found many bugs in my function calls or even application code when I stopped excluding them.